# The Wifi of my laptop (ASUS 2015) sometimes disconnect itself with no reasons

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, connection, asus-laptop

I can be playing online video games or in the web seeing a video in Youtube when, with no reason, the icon Wifi show that there no exist any near Wifi, causing the disconnect of my laptop internet. This can be fixed just going there and research wifi or turning off and on it again. Automatically will be connected with the Wifi that was connected before. This happens a many of time in a short time periods forcing me to play online games with ethernet cable and no wifi.

I have been trying a lot of things:
Update Wifi Drivers
Change Wifi's configuration
Literally restore as default my laptop

But it still happening al the time.

And I'm sure that is my computer because the rest of smart devices have no problem with my router.

Do you know what could be the problem?

Laptop SO: Windows 10.
Laptop Model: Asus 2015 (Don't remember my model name)
8 gb ram
Intel i7
Nvidia 800m series (I don't remember what)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't be so quick to think the problem is only with your PC. If you are over taxing the wireless router its default behavior may be simply to kick the device that is over-using it off. So have you checked for and update the firmware of your wireless router? And what is the specific model number of your router?

Comment: No I haven't updated my router yet. Anyway, I'm pretty sure that the problem is my computer because it have been happening in another routers.

Comment: Please open your device manager to check your WiFi hardware. Then [edit] the question and add that information. The graphics card is irrelevant, the actual laptopt model that you didn't mention may be relevant but probably not.